# Lebesgue's Singular Function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ denote the Cantor set, i.e. the set of points $x\in[0,1]$ such that $x=\sum_\limits{k}^\infty\frac{a_k}{3^k}$ where $a_k$ takes valuse $0$ or $2$. For each $x=\sum_\limits k^\infty\frac{a_k}{3^k}\: \in S$, we define $F(x)=\sum_\limits k^\infty \frac{b_k}{2^k}$, where $b_k=\frac{a_k}{2}$ (in particular, $b_k$ only takes values $0$ or $1$). On each interval $\left(\frac{3k+1}{3^{n+1}},\frac{3k+2}{3^{n+1}}\right)$, we define $F$ to be a constant equal to the common value on both end points of the interval. Prove that $F$ is continuous, increasing, and has derivative equal to zero almost everywhere.

Showing that $F$ is increasing is a little straightforward. But do you have any ideas to show this is continuous and has derivative equal to zero almost everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Show that the points where the derivative is $0$ are the interior points of the set of all points that have a base-$3$ expansion in which at least one digit is $1,$ i.e. one of the numbers you called $a_k$ is $1.$

The set of points at which $a_1=1$ has measure $1/3,$ and is a closed interval. The function described is not differentiable at the two endpoints of that interval, but it is differentiable everywhere in the interior.

The set of points at which $a_2=1$ is a union of two intervals and similar comments apply. Its measure is $2/9.$

The set of points at which $a_3=1$ is a union of four intvervals and similar comments apply. Its measure is $4/27.$

The sequence of these meausures is geometric, so you can find their sum, and when you've done that you will see the answer to part of your question.

That this function is continuous surprised me when I first saw it. But remember that the only kind of discontinuity that a monotone function can have is a jump. You just need to show that there are no jumps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did you mean $a_k$ or $b_k$ instead?

Comment: @JeshurunHelp : I meant $a_k,$ the base-three digit. $\qquad$